# How to map data of react query's dependent query

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-query

Using `react-query` v.3, what's the best way to get the data of a promise response of a `useQuery()` dependant query?

I cannot `map()` directly to the data response.

ref.: https://react-query.tanstack.com/guides/dependent-queries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- you can check if data is available via `isSuccess`:

```
 const { isSuccess, data } = useQuery(
   ['projects', userId],
   getProjectsByUser,
   {
     // The query will not execute until the userId exists
     enabled: !!userId,
   }
 )
 
 if (isSuccess) {
    return data.map(...) // <-- data is guaranteed to be defined
 }
```

- you can simply check if data exists, or use [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining):

```
 const { isSuccess, data } = useQuery(
   ['projects', userId],
   getProjectsByUser,
   {
     // The query will not execute until the userId exists
     enabled: !!userId,
   }
 )
 
 return data?.map(...) ?? null // <-- make sure to handle fallback with ??
```